# Set denoting a vector space of any dimension

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, vectors

For vectors with $n$ dimensions, I have seen that the vector space is written $\mathbb{R}^n$, but obviously this only represents a specific dimension. Is there a concise notation for a vector space of any dimension? (i.e. it contains $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, etc.)

Comment: Your assumption is false: there are lots of $n$-dimensional spaces other than $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: On what ground are you assuming that "throwing all them together" in a single collection" what you get is still a vector space ?

Comment: Yes, we usually denote a vector space of arbitrary dimension by a single name, typically $V$.